# Why do I get the error message for my SQL code?

Tags: postgresql

I want to run this small SQL code I get this error message: "ERROR:  relation "spel" does not exist"

This is my code at the moment:

```
ALTER TABLE Spel DROP CONSTRAINT spel_spelid_fkey;
ALTER TABLE Spel DROP CONSTRAINT spel_namn_fkey;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Spel;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Plattform;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Företag;

CREATE TABLE Spel 
(
    SpelID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    namn varchar(50),
    genre text,
    år date,
    Åldergräns char(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Företag 
(
    FöretagID varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    Företag text,
    Högk text
);

CREATE TABLE Plattform 
(
    PlattformID integer,
    Plattform varchar (50),

    PRIMARY KEY (PlattformID, Plattform)
);

ALTER TABLE Spel
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (SpelID) REFERENCES Plattform (PlattformID),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (namn) REFERENCES Företag (FöretagID);
```

What am I missing that I don't see?

I made the tables into alter tables so that they are after `Företag` and `Plattform`.

Comment: What line does the error message point to?

Comment: "I made the tables into alter tables so that they are after Företag and Plattform" what do you mean by this? Is it a change you made to the code? If yes, please edit the code to reflect it.

If you did not alter the code, your problem is that you try to execute `ALTER TABLE Spel` before the table exists as it is only created later.

Comment: Or when the table was originally created that was done as `CREATE TABLE "Spel" ...`, in which case you now have to maintain the double quotes in the name, as in `ALTER TABLE "Spel" ...` per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: the error message does not point to any specific line in the code.

Comment: I meant that I tested by moving the "Spel" table to appear after all of the other tables and therefore removing the last bit of "ALTER TABLE Spel", but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Execute your SQL statements one by one and you will see exactly where it fails. Then you know what to fix

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. As has already been asked, provide exact information on what statement was executed when you got the error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you see. I get `ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "plattform"`, and that makes sense, because you created the primary key on `plattform` in the wrong way.

Comment: @medina_01 do you have a table named Spel before you run this script?

Answer (score -3):

In PostgreSQL table names need to be quoted unless they are lower case e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Spel ( ... )
```

will create a table called spel (note lower case).

so you need to use:

```
CREATE TABLE "Spel" ( ... )
```

and instead of :

```
ALTER TABLE Spel DROP CONSTRAINT spel_spelid_fkey;
```

you need to use

```
ALTER TABLE "Spel" DROP CONSTRAINT spel_spelid_fkey;
```

I try and use all lower case table / relation names so I don't have to worry about this.

Comment: In your example it would not make a difference `CREATE TABLE Spel ` would create a table named `spel` and `ALTER TABLE Spel ...` would operate on a table named `spel`. Either correct your 'answer' or delete it because as of now it is meaningless.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  The first line of the OPs question is giving the error message stated.  I was assuming a table named Spel already exists and the reason it was not being altered was that Postgres needs relation names need to be quoted to keep their case.  If this is not the case then I expect the OP to to tell me so.

Comment: An answer is based on what is known not what is assumed. Otherwise all you are doing is making a guess. Get the information from the OP first then provide an answer.

Comment: If there is no Spel table before this script is run then the question makes no sense.  It seems most likely that this issue is related to the way Postgres treats table names.  I will quite happily remove my answer if this is incorrect.