# I get error message when trying to run SQL code

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the name of my games and what platforms they can be played on but I keeps getting an error for the "spel_plattform".

This is the error: : "ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "spel_plattform" LINE 124: JOIN Plattform on Spel.spelid = spel_plattform.spelid;"

This is my code:

```
drop table if exists spel_plattform CASCADE;
drop table if exists Spel;
drop table if exists Plattform;
drop table if exists Company;

create table Company (
        CompanyID integer primary key,
        Companyname text,
        HQ text
);

create table Plattform (
        PlattformID text primary key,
        Plattform text
);

create table Spel (
        SpelID integer primary key,
        företagid integer,
        spel text,
        genre text,
        år date,
        Åldergräns integer,
       
        foreign key (företagID) references Company (CompanyID)
);

create table spel_plattform (
        spelID integer,
        plattformID text,
    
        primary key (spelID, plattformID),
        foreign key (spelID) references spel(SpelID),
        foreign key (plattformID) references plattform(plattformID)

);

insert into Company (CompanyID, Companyname, HQ)
    values (1, 'Capcom', 'Japan'),
            (2, 'From', 'Japan'),
            (3, 'Zeekeers', 'USA'),
            (4, 'Frostbite', 'Sweden'),
            (5, 'Red Barrel', 'Canada');
        

insert into Plattform (PlattformID, Plattform)
    values ('NES', 'Nintendo Entertainment System'),
            ('PS4', 'PlayStation 4'),
            ('PC', 'Personal Computer'),
            ('XB-SX', 'Xbox-Series X'),
            ('PS5', 'PLayStation 5'),
            ('N-S', 'Nintendo Switch');
            


insert into Spel (SpelID, företagID, spel, genre, år, Åldergräns)
    values  (10, 1, 'Zelda', 'Adventure', '2015-10-12', 7),
            (20, 1, 'Animal Crossing', 'Puzzle', '2015-10-15', 3),
            (30, 2, 'Bloodborne', 'A-RPG', '2017-09-09', 18),
            (40, 2, 'Elden Ring', 'A-RPG', '2022-01-01', 18),
            (50, 3, 'Lethal Company', 'Horror', '2023-10-28', 18),
            (60, 4, 'Battlefield 1', 'FPS', '2018-11-02', 18),
            (70, 5, 'Outlast', 'Horror', '2012-06-18', 18);
            
insert into spel_plattform (spelID, plattformID)
    values (10, 'NES'),
            (10, 'PS4'),
            (20, 'NES'),
            (20, 'N-S'),
            (30, 'PS4'),
            (40, 'PS4'),
            (40, 'PC'),
            (50, 'PC'),
            (60, 'XB-SX'),
            (60, 'PS5'),
            (70, 'PC');
SELECT Spel.spel, spel_plattform.plattformID
FROM Spel
JOIN Plattform on Spel.spelid = spel_plattform.spelid;
```

I tried running it but get the error message. Another question: is it possible to get the full names from the "platform" column in "plattform" table even though there are no foreign keys attached to it?

Comment: I am also wondering when I have to be careful about case sensitivity. Does it apply all the time or only when I join tables?

Comment: It's your last query, the select statement. And as you can see, there is no table spel_plattform in the FROM or JOIN.

Comment: For case sensitivity in Postgresql, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798517/2112722)

Comment: in your query you `join Plattform` but you use `spel_plattform` for the columns

Comment: 1) You do have a FK between `spel_platform` and `Plattform` as `foreign key (plattformID) references plattform(plattformID)`. Just add `plattform.plattform` to the select. 2) Case sensitivity was already explained to your here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77549716/why-do-i-get-the-error-message-for-my-sql-code. The rules have not changed since then.